# char* value changing after use of fgets

Tags: c

so my first question would be. Does fgets overwrite other char* values?

Otherwise, I'm not really sure how I have messed up my mallocs. Below is the code where the value is changing. First line is where the variable is being created.

```
data[dataIndex++] = createVariable(varName, 1, value, -1, line, NULL);
```

The code where the variable is being created

```
Variable *createVariable(char *name, int type, int val, int len, int line, char *string)
    {
        Variable *var = malloc(sizeof(Variable));
        var->name = name;
        var->setting = type;
        var->num = val;
        var->length = len;
        var->line = line;
        var->string = string;
        return var;
    }
```

What data looks like and how it was created.

```
Variable **data;
data = malloc(4 * sizeof(Variable *));
```

Forgot to add this, but below is my fgets code

```
if (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, in) == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
```

Comment: I have understood nothing.What is the question? fgets writes to the character array pointed to by the expression line. What is the problem?

Comment: @Vlad Copying pointer not pointed-to data, I think (see answer). Maybe?? Probably?

Comment: Apologies, essentially. the char* name in data[0], for example, is become random characters. After I create a variable, data[0] looks like this -> data[0]->name = 0x6054d0 "val01". But after running fgets. data[0]->name = 0x6054d0 ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line in your `createVariable` function:

```c
    var->name = name;
```

What this does is copy the *pointer* given as the first argument to the `name` field in the `var` structure; it *doesn't* make a (separate) copy of the data that is pointed to! So, assuming you call `createVariable` many times with the same variable as the first argument, then *every* object created will have the *same* address in its `name` field, and any modifications you make to any of them (via `fgets`) will change *all* of them.

To get round this, you need to allocate *new* memory for the `name` field, each time you call the `createVariable` function, then copy the string data to it. The simplest way to do this is using the [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) function:

```c
Variable *createVariable(char *name, int type, int val, int len, int line, char *string)
    {
        Variable *var = malloc(sizeof(Variable));
        var->name = strdup(name);
        //...
        var->string = strdup(string);
        //...
```

But note, you will now need to be sure to free that memory from *each* object when you (eventually) delete it. Something like this:

```c
void deleteVariable(Variable** var)
{
    free((*var)->name);   // free the name memory
    free((*var)->string); // free the string memory
    free(*var);           // free the actual structure
    *var = NULL; // set the pointer to NULL - to prevent multiple frees
}
```

EDIT: Just re-read your question, and noticed that you are making the same mistake with the `string` field! The same fix needs to be applied to that!

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. I'll add the delete code as well.